# A sequence with 2 accumulation points which, intuitively, converges to 0

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have been thinking about this question for a little while: does there exist a sequence $(a_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that:

1. $(a_n)$ possesses at least two accumulation points;
2. $\left( \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right) \to -\frac{1}{2}.$

Intuitively, when $n$ is very large, we have $a_{n+1} \approx -\frac{a_n}{2},$ so that our hypothetical sequence looks like it converges to 0 while alternating between positive and negative numbers (the obvious example being $(-1/2)^n$). However, this contradicts our first hypothesis. Thus I have essentially two questions:

1. Does condition (2.) imply that $(a_n)$ converges to 0?
2. If not, does such a sequence exist?

Thanks!

Comment: The answer to (1) is yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to question 1 is Yes.
If $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\to -\frac12$ then for suffciciently large $n$ (say $n\ge N$) we have $-\frac23<\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<-\frac13$, hence $\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}<\frac23$. Then $|a_n|\le \left(\frac 23\right)^{n-N}|a_{N}|$ for all $n>N$, which makes $a_n\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

As remarked in the comments, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=-\frac12$ readily implies that $a_n\to0$ by the Ratio test.

A convergent sequence in a metric space cannot have more than one accumulation point, since if a convergent sequence accumulates at a point, then it converges to that point. Hence, no sequence exists satisfying both conditions that you gave.